# where is inittab present in kernel source

Tags: linux, login, init, yocto

I wanted to edit some thing in `inittab` file. Where can I find the `inittab` in kernel source? I need to build the kernel after making the changes. I need to remove the login prompt after booting. I know that I can change in `/etc/inittab` but if I do that after reboot I lose the changes. I am using embedded Linux Yocto project.

Comment: Why not switch to **systemd** exclusively and drop the whole `inittab` thing?

Comment: when I googled i read about inittab. I will try to use systemd. can you give me some idea how to proceed

Comment: See [Using systemd Exclusively](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-systemd-exclusively) from the the development manual.

Answer (score 7):

`/etc/inittab` is a feature of the init system in use, and not part of the kernel.

After the kernel has completed its part of the system initialisation it will create the first user-space process.  Typically this is `/sbin/init` but it can change.

Now what `/sbin/init` does depends on the type of init system you have.  The traditional "sysvinit" will read /etc/inittab and perform actions based on that.

`upstart` is an alternative init system (used, for example, in RedHat 6); it doesn't use `inittab` except for determining the default run level.

More recently, `systemd` doesn't use `inittab` at all.

So if you're looking to modify how `inittab` you'll need to look outside the kernel and at the init system instead.

UPDATED:

In the standard *poky* build of Yocto you'll see a default `inittab` at

```
meta/recipes-core/sysvinit/sysvinit-inittab/inittab
```

There is also a script at

```
meta/recipes-core/sysvinit/sysvinit-inittab_2.88dsf.bb
```

which appends `getty` lines to this based on your `meta/conf` entries.

You could either edit the template `inittab` directly or the build process script (if based on config entries) according to your need.

Comment: thank you @Stephen Harris for the clear explanation... let me check it and give it a try.

Comment: i tried adding the --autologin root to the getty line. When i try boot it is giving error like getty --autologin unrecognized command